# JavaScript syntax advice: Invalid left hand side in prefix expression when auto formatting

Tags: javascript, syntax, operators, legacy-code

I inherited a codebase aka "legacy code" and I am very careful not to break anything. I stumbled upon an error while auto-formatting.

The purpose of the function is to sort a chart. I commented the portion I do not understand:

```
function sortChartBy(field,dir=1) {
    if(g_sortMethod != field){
        g_sortDir = 1;
    }
    g_sortMethod = field;
    g_sortDir = g_sortDir * -1 * dir;
    
    var ranks = g_chart["ranks"];
    var sortMethod = g_sortMethod;
    var sortDir = g_sortDir;
    
    var sortFunc = undefined;
    if(field == "release_date"){
        sortFunc = function(a,b){
            var aVal = a[sortMethod];
            var bVal = b[sortMethod];
            if(aVal == "1970-01-01") aVal = "9999--99-99";
            if(bVal == "1970-01-01") bVal = "9999-99-99";
            if(aVal < bVal) return -1 * sortDir;
            if(aVal > bVal) return  1 * sortDir;
            return 0;
        };
    }else{
        sortFunc = function(a,b){
      var aVal = a[sortMethod];
      var bVal = b[sortMethod];

      // ###### QUESTION HERE ########################################
      if (aVal == -1 && bVal !=- -1) return 1; 
      // 'bVal !=- -1' What does that mean? Why '-' directly after '!='

      if (aVal != -1 && bVal == -1) return -1;
      if (aVal < bVal) return -1 * sortDir;
      if (aVal > bVal) return  1 * sortDir;
      return 0;
        };
    }
    
    ranks.sort(sortFunc);
    renderChart();
}
```

I use IntelliJ as an IDE. When I use auto format the '-' minus character after the '!=' moves one character to the right showing the line as

```
if (aVal == -1 && bVal != --1) return 1; // Invalid left hand side in prefix expression
```

Now Intellij shows an error stating `Invalid left hand side in prefix expression` and marking the '1' with the red error underline.

I don't understand why there are two minuses seperated with a space `!=- -1` in the original code and why Intellij formats this into an error. The code seems to work fine in the original code. I have never seen `!=-` in JavaScript. To me this does not seem to be valid.

Please explain why the line `if (aVal == -1 && bVal !=- -1) return 1;` seems to work fine, but then gets autoformatted into an error.

What should the correct code look like?

Comment: not sure why they do it, but `console.log(- -1)`

Comment: That's basically a typo. `--1` is invalid code, because it tries to use the prefix decrement operator (`--`) on a literal (`1`). The prefix decrement operator's job is to decrement the value stored in a variable or property; it *writes back* to what it decrements. You can't write back to a literal. That code should probably be just `-1`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the prompt response. Please write it as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Ran it through prettier and it formats it to: `if (aVal == -1 && bVal != -(-1)) return 1;` Perhaps write a test with expected input and output of the function to make sure your changes don't break anything :)

Comment: We don't post "it's a typo" answers on SO, we just close the question. But now I'm **really** interested to understand the code that does parse.

Comment: @Mellet - Doh! Of course, that's how it parses. Unary `-`, unary `-`, and `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please explain why the line `if (aVal == -1 && bVal !=- -1) return 1;` seems to work fine, but then gets autoformatted into an error.

The formatter is indeed breaking that code, but I suspect it was already broken. :-) But the formatter is violating a fundamental principle: It's chaning the meaning of the code (in this case, from valid-but-probably-wrong syntax to invalid syntax :-D ).

Thanks to [Mellet mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66187318/javascript-syntax-advice-invalid-left-hand-side-in-prefix-expression-when-auto#comment117015275_66187318) running it through a different formatter, my afternoon-sleepy brain understands why the original parses: It's the unary `-` operator being used twice.

So the code is `!= - -1` which is `!= -(-1)` which is `!= 1`.

But it's probably a typo and the check was probably supposed to be against `-1`, not `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 
I tested `-1` and `1`. In both cases the sorting is done correctly. I use `bVal != 1` now.
I added a comment with the original code just in case.

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant - That sort callback code is much more complicated than it needs to be. If `aVal` and `bVal` are numbers, literally the callback could be `return (a[sortMethod] - b[sortMethod]) * sortDir;` assuming that `sortDir` is `1` for an ascending sort and `-1` for a descending sort. Similarly, the previous callback  comparing date strings could replace the last three lines of `return`s with simply: `return aVal.localeCompare(bVal) * sortDir;`.